# How to check every directory size using one shell command?

Tags: linux, shell, mysql

I want to get database sizes for -

> test, mysql, performance_schema, sakila, information_schema

```
[root@linux data]# ls -ltrh
总用量 32M
drwx------ 2 mysql root  4.0K 4月  27 17:44 test
drwx------ 2 mysql root  4.0K 4月  27 17:44 mysql
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql  28K 4月  27 17:44 mysql-bin.000001
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 1.1M 4月  27 17:44 mysql-bin.000002
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql  27K 4月  27 17:49 mysql-bin.000003
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 1.1M 4月  27 17:49 mysql-bin.000004
drwx------ 2 mysql mysql 4.0K 4月  27 17:50 performance_schema
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql  27K 4月  27 17:50 mysql-bin.000005
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 1.1M 4月  27 17:50 mysql-bin.000006
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 5.0M 4月  27 18:02 ib_logfile1
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql  238 4月  27 18:02 mysql-bin.index
srwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql    0 4月  27 18:02 mysql.sock
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql    6 4月  27 18:02 mysql.pid
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 2.1K 4月  27 21:07 error.log
drwx------ 2 mysql mysql 4.0K 4月  27 21:51 lijunda
drwx------ 2 mysql mysql 4.0K 4月  28 09:12 sakila
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql  22K 4月  28 09:12 mysql-bin.000007
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql  18M 4月  28 09:12 ibdata1
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 5.0M 4月  28 09:12 ib_logfile0
```

when I use the command below, all directories become 4.0k. It's not what I wanted.

```
[root@linux data]# ls -ltrhd */
drwx------ 2 mysql root  4.0K 4月  27 17:44 test/
drwx------ 2 mysql root  4.0K 4月  27 17:44 mysql/
drwx------ 2 mysql mysql 4.0K 4月  27 17:50 performance_schema/
drwx------ 2 mysql mysql 4.0K 4月  27 21:51 lijunda/
drwx------ 2 mysql mysql 4.0K 4月  28 09:12 sakila/
```

How to display these directories proper size?

Answer (score 3):

Try the command `du`(disk usage).

Comment: To get summarised results for each folder try `du -s */.`

Answer (score 1):

I'd have commented the answer from torchhound... but I'm still too new for comments.
I also think `du` suits your need. I would use the `-b` (report in bytes) or `-h` (human readable), just to be sure of the magnitude of the numbers; otherwise you'll have to guess and although you will probably get it right, do it just in case.
My command line:

```
du -sb *
```